# Overriding compareTo on self-referencing object (parent/child relationship)

Tags: sorting, grails, compareto

I'm trying to implement compareTo on a domain class in grails so I can return a SortedSet. I want my sorted set to be ordered by parent name, then by "child" name. For example (P=parent, C=child):

- P-1

  - C-1
  - C-2
- P-2

  - C-3
  - C-4

My class looks something like this:

```
class Issue implements Comparable {
 String name
 Issue parent

@Override
public int compareTo(obj){
  if(obj.parent!=null && this.parent!=null){
   parent.name.compareTo(obj.parent.name)
  }else{
      //What do I compare to sort the children relative to their parents?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're looking for is sorted sets, would just implementing Comparable on Issue and using sort orders on the mappings suffice?

```
class Issue implements Comparable {
 String name
 Issue parent
 SortedSet children

 static hasMany = [children : Issue]
 static belongsTo = [parent : Issue]
 static mapping = {
    sort 'name'
    children sort:'name'
 }    

@Override
public int compareTo(obj){
  if(obj){
    this.name?.compareTo(obj.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! When I tried that, I get a NullPointerException - parent is null for at least one instance. I can write a custom SQL query to do what I want, but couldn't figure out how to do in HQL.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I meant this.name instead of parent.name.

Comment: Um, actually...what if there's more than one level of parent/child nesting? Just created a 3rd level instance (i.e subchild) and your implementation seems to order it right to the top - any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand "right to the top", can you give an example?  Also I realized that the hasMany and belongsTo were missing, so added those.

Comment: Thanks Kaleb! My class already contains a hasMany property, so...If I added, say, SC-1 as a subchild under C1, it's order is placed as the first element in the set. Hopefully this clarifies. 
I've yet to try a recursive solution with your suggestion